# Getting "ArSession_update failed with status -7" error on logcat

Tags: android, git, unity-game-engine, arcore

Hi i am getting an error when i try to run my unity apk app which consits of ArCore on my android phone.(Android 9 and 10). Note (I have not tested it on less than 9)

When i open my app it asks me for every permission that is necessary for a camera to open.
But when the scene starts my camera does not open and gives a black screen.

When i looked at log cat it gave me following :-

################ BUILD ID

BUILD_USERNAME build-secure BUILD_HOSTNAME oxf6.prod.google.com BUILD_DIRECTORY /export/hda3/borglet/remote_hdd_fs_dirs/rabbit-prod.secure-alloc.build-secure.113.536079300067.14b334fb3717c109/mount/tmpfs/rabbit/workspaces/11337855945316597703/google3 BUILD_EMBED_LABEL arcore_1.13_20191007_RC010 BUILD_BLAZE_RELEASE release blaze-2019.09.28-1 (mainline @271678982) WORKSPACE_STATUS_COMMAND_ARGUMENT /export/hda3/borglet/remote_hdd_fs_dirs/rabbit-prod.secure-alloc.build-secure.113.536079300067.14b334fb3717c109/mount/tmpfs/rabbit/workspaces/11337855945316597703/-oxf6-a188-33362-107a9504df02b-595b4d851bebd_embed_changelist_ VERIFIABLE 1 BUILD_CLIENT build-secure-info:source-uri BUILD_DEPOT_PATH //depot/branches/vr_arcore_release_branch/273204670.2/google3 BUILD_CLIENT_MINT_STATUS 1 BUILD_USERNAME vr-builder BUILD_DIRECTORY /google/src/files/276618081/depot/branches/vr_arcore_release_branch/273204670.2/OVERLAY_READONLY/google3 BUILD_ID a628e9ed-44d4-4db7-94e6-109043b4f5bc BUILD_REQUEST_ID bbq-9384cf0e-873d-4d93-8057-6a439341c962 SRCFSD_TASK_BNS /bns/ox/borg/ox/bns/build-secure/rabbit-prod.secure-srcfsd/113 BUILDRABBIT_DEBUG_BBQID http://go/bbqid?uuid=bbq-9384cf0e-873d-4d93-8057-6a439341c962 BUILDRABBIT_TASK_BNS /bns/ox/borg/ox/bns/build-secure/rabbit-prod.secure-worker/113 BUILD_BASELINE_CHANGELIST 273204670 BUILDRABBIT_DEBUG_BUILD_ID http://go/buildrabbit-build-id/a628e9ed-44d4-4db7-94e6-109043b4f5bc SOURCE_URI googlefile:/google_src/files/276618081/depot/branches/vr_arcore_release_branch/273204670.2/OVERLAY_READONLY/google3 BUILDRABBIT_BLAZE_BINARY_PATH /google/src/files/276618081/depot/branches/vr_arcore_release_branch/273204670.2/OVERLAY_READONLY/google3/tools/blaze BUILD_REQUEST_ID bbq-9384cf0e-873d-4d93-8057-6a439341c962 OBJFSD_TASK_BNS /bns/ox/borg/ox/bns/build-secure/rabbit-prod.secure-objfsd/113 BUILD_VERSION_MAP map 0 { // } BUILD_CHANGELIST 276618081 BUILD_WORKER_VERSION buildrabbit-worker_20191018_0_RC00 BUILDRABBIT_DEBUG_LOG_ARCHIVE_DIR http://cnsviewer/cns/ox-d/home/build-logs/log_archives/a6/a628e9ed-44d4-4db7-94e6-109043b4f5bc

################## BEGIN

ARCoreError: third_party/arcore/ar/core/c_api/session_lite_c_api.cc:51  https://cs.corp.google.com/piper///depot/google3/third_party/arcore/ar/core/c_api/session_lite_c_api.cc?g=0&l=51

################### END

2019-11-18 15:36:19.279 20317-20356/? E/ArPresto: ArPresto::ArSession_update failed with status -7.
2019-11-18 15:36:19.298 20317-20356/? E/native: error_policy_util.cc:151

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please take a look at the tour page (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and at the "How to ask a good question" page (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so we can help you!

Comment: Hi, since its been a month did you find a solution?