# my arcore pro throw couldn't find "libarsceneview_jni.so", anyone can help me?

Tags: android

my project throw error which stack trace like follows:
2019-11-28 13:58:32.207 17722-17722/com.whyhow.xunguang E/ArSceneView: Error loading libarsceneview_jni.so
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.whyhow.xunguang-Gh73eEgV3Gs0coSIxAYuHQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.whyhow.xunguang-Gh73eEgV3Gs0coSIxAYuHQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.whyhow.xunguang-Gh73eEgV3Gs0coSIxAYuHQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /product/lib64]]] couldn't find "libarsceneview_jni.so"
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1012)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1672)
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.ArSceneView.reportEngineType(SourceFile:232)
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.ArSceneView.resumeSession(SourceFile:51)
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.ArSceneView.resume(SourceFile:41)
        at com.whyhow.xunguang.ar.SceneActivity.onResume(SceneActivity.kt:241)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1456)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7614)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4412)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4470)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:51)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:145)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2199)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)

Comment: Got the same problem, don't know how to fix. Ar Core my be the cause. I am using a Xiaiomi Pocophone

Comment: this error is not fatal error, my app can run although throws this error, we can ignor this error.

Comment: oke my not be realted but im getting this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58915573/getting-arsession-update-failed-with-status-7-error-on-logcat) along this error. App not chrashing but the cmaera wont be displayed